# How to prevent data from submitting in database when text box is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbx1" ValidateEmptyText="true" OnServerValidate="validating" Text="Please Enter Name!" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I've Tried it, just working but I don't know how to stop data from entering!.

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = txtbx1.Text;
        string b = txtbx2.Text;
        string c = txtbx3.Text;
        string d = txtbx4.Text;
        string es = txtbx5.Text;
        string f = txtbx6.Text;
        if (txtbx1.Text.ToString().Equals(a) || txtbx2.Text.ToString().Equals(b) || txtbx3.Text.ToString().Equals(c) || txtbx4.Text.ToString().Equals(d) || txtbx5.Text.ToString().Equals(es) || txtbx6.Text.ToString().Equals(f))

        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
                using (conn)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("addstd", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtbx1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", txtbx2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollment", txtbx3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtbx4.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchcode", txtbx5.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", txtbx6.Text);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Inserted Successfully!')</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else if (txtbx1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty ||txtbx3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx4.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx5.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx6.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Please Enter Complete Information!";

        }
    }
```

this is complete code from back I've tried it but does not works , its just keep showing error message but also submits data even when textbox is empty

Comment: Use a `RequiredFieldValidator`. But always check the value before storing it in the database also.

Comment: Did It already still not working

Comment: Then you should provide related markup & code behind to let us check the problem and put a solution accordingly :)

Comment: `Not working`? What does that mean exactly? As @TetsuyaYamamoto says without some more info there's little we can do.

Comment: Enable or Disable the Submit button on validation

Comment: if (txtbx1.Text.ToString().Equals(a) || txtbx2.Text.ToString().Equals(b) || txtbx3.Text.ToString().Equals(c) || txtbx4.Text.ToString().Equals(d) || txtbx5.Text.ToString().Equals(es) || txtbx6.Text.ToString().Equals(f))

Comment: This does not help.... What is the expected result and what is actually happening and is the problem in the Validator or in code behind?

Comment: protected void validating(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            args.IsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx1.Text.Trim());
            if (args.Value.Length != 0)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false
            }
        }    this is that method I provided in onservervalidate

Comment: when i click submit button its showing message but entering data in database as well

Comment: Your if condition will always be true, because you are comparing the value with itself, so atleast one condition is true and it will execute the db save logic.

Comment: I've just edited I gave inserting code to else whit "!= null" property but it still adds data

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there is a check like below.

```
if (txtbx1.Text.ToString().Equals(a) || txtbx2.Text.ToString().Equals(b) || txtbx3.Text.ToString().Equals(c) || txtbx4.Text.ToString().Equals(d) || txtbx5.Text.ToString().Equals(es) || txtbx6.Text.ToString().Equals(f))
{
  // your code
}
```

Replace the above code with your else part.

```
if (txtbx1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty ||txtbx3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx4.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx5.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtbx6.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
  Label1.Visible = true;
  Label1.Text = "Please Enter Complete Information!";
}
else
{
  //database save logic
}
```

Apart from this, a required field validator should work.